# Portainer Setup on Window Server 2016

Tags: windows, docker, containers, windows-server-2016, portainer

I followed the steps below to create a portainer container on my host's port `9000`.

I am getting the following error:

> C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: named pipe mounts are not supported on this version of Windows.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Allow Docker Connection Through Firewall by this:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Docker" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=2375 enable=yes profile=domain,private,public
   ```
2. Configure Docker Deamon to listen on both pipe and TCP:

   2.1. `StopService docker`

   2.2. `dockerd --unregister-service`

   2.3. `dockerd -H npipe:// -H 0.0.0.0:2375 --registerservice`

   2.4. `Start-Service docker`
3. Pull portainer image: docker pull portainer/portainer
4. Creating a volume: docker volume create portainer_data
5. Run Portainer

   ```
   docker run -d --name portainer -p 9000:9000 --mount type=npipe,source=\\.\pipe\docker_engine,target=\\.\pipe\docker_engine --mount type=volume,source=portainer_data,target=C:\data portainer/portainer
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`named pipe mounts are not supported on this version of Windows.`

This error means that your Docker version do not support bind mounting named pipes into containers.

First you must check the Docker version on your system, can be done with `docker version`.

Then, you need to ensure that your Docker version is >= 17.09 and use one of these solutions:

- Docker version = 17.09, bind mount the named pipe as a volume

`docker run -d --name portainer -p 9000:9000 -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine --mount type=volume,source=portainer_data,target=C:\data portainer/portainer`

- Docker version >= 18.03, named pipe bind mounts are supported and your command should just work.